# Cannot edit or add table via table editor in MySQL workbench

Tags: mysql-workbench

I noticed a few weeks ago that I wasn't able to edit a table anymore. When I tried to create a new table, the same thing happened. The editor just blocks the inputfields. As you can see here:

[image]

I know that this has nothing to do with the foreign keys, since the table I tried to alter doesn't have a foreign key yet and it also happens when I try to create a new table.

I can add/alter tables when I use a SQL script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably the victim of unlucky screen division. Your table editor is not large enough to show the columns list. Try dragging the splitter between the editor bottom and the output area down to make the editor area bigger. That should reveal the columns list again.

Also collaps the table editor header (using the double arrow in the upper right corner of the editor). This will save more space for the column list.

[image]